# How to get old value of entity association?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I can get old values for simple fields in doctrine events:
**preUpdate** - by `$args->getEntityChangeSet()` or `$args->getOldValue()`
**onFlush** - by `$uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity)`

But I don't understand how to do it for associations (OneToMany, ManyToMany). Change set doesn't contain them.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change sets of inverse side of such associations simply do not contain those entries. **Thus, there is no simple way to retrieve the initial state of all associated entities**. That being said, you gave pretty much everything you might need if you simply want to access the change sets of the associated entities.

In a `preUpdate` event of an Entity listener of an inverse side of a OneToMany association, you could do the following:

```
public function preUpdate(Category $category, PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{   
    $uow = $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork();
    foreach($category->getElements() as $elt)
    {
        $eltChangeSet = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($elt);
        // Do something with the retrieved info...
    }
}
```

In this example, you could also call `$category->getElements()->getDeleteDiff()` and `$category->getElements()->getInsertDiff()`to retrieve elements that were added or removed to the [PersistentCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.PersistentCollection.html). Note however that these two methods are marked as INTERNAL, so it might be better not to rely on them too much.

Since you can have the old values of your associated entities, you could try to clone them and recreate their previous state from there. The main drawback is that you only have access to changes that happened on fields that are tracked by Doctrine, others changes are lost.

*Note: since the change set does not take into account associations, update events of the inverse side won't be triggered if only the associated entities states have changed (their respective change sets won't be empty but the inverse side won't be notified of that).*